# How to get a MouseWheel Event to fire only once in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouseevent, mousewheel

So I want to fire a function only once every time a user scrolls up or down via the Mousewheel. See: [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y4eUF/2/). The issue is that even though I have the e.preventDefault(), the function still fires multiple times.

The goal is for the function to fire only once whenever a user scrolls up or down. Similar to this [site](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html).

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
var sq = {};
sq = document;
if (sq.addEventListener) {
    sq.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler(), false);
    sq.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler(), false);
} else {
    sq.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler());
}

function MouseWheelHandler() {
    return function (e) {
        var e = window.event || e;
        var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
        if (delta < 0) {
            /* Scroll Down */
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("Down. I want this to happen only once");

        } else {
            /* Scroll Up */
            console.log("up. I want this to happen only once");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/one/ - or, since you're not actually using jQuery, just call [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener) inside your handler. But I suspect that what you said you wanted isn't actually what you wanted?

Comment: It's probably not so much that the event only fires once, but that there is a timeout of some kind preventing actions from being taken too often.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/issues/36#issuecomment-59883575) has helped me:

```
var isMoving=false;

$(document).bind("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll", function(event, delta) {
   event.preventDefault();
   if (isMoving) return;
   navigateTo();
});

function navigateTo(){
   isMoving = true;
   setTimeout(function() {
    isMoving=false;
   },2000);
}
```

Basically you have a isMoving variable that is set depending on if your animation or whatever you do is in progress. Even though user scrolls multiple times with mousewheel in one "flick", the function fires only once.

Answer (score -3):

```
   ​$(document).ready(function(){
var up=false;
var down=false;
        $('#foo').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
            if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0 && up=false)  {
up=true;
down=false;
                $(this).text('scrolling up !');
            }
            elseif(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0 && down=false){
down=true;
up=false;
                $(this).text('scrolling down !');
            }
        });
    });
```

And [here](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/) is a plug in you can use it

Comment: `on` is preferred since jQuery 1.7 and why do you think this will only fire once?

Comment: sorry.i update it...now it fire once while user is scrolling up
and then fire again while user is scrolling down

Comment: And it's very simple if just use that plug in i told

Comment: I downvoted this. First off you have to correct your code. Use `else if` not `elseif`. Check conditions using `up == false` or `!up`, not `up=false`. And there's no logic to this anyway. This will trigger only when scrolling up. And when doing so, it will return "scrolling up" and "scrolling down" one after the other. Heres how it plays out with errors corrected: http://jsfiddle.net/34LgD/