# mousewheel event is too fast. How to disable it

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

I am trying to bring in an effect like hugeinc.com in my website udowalzfinal.umatechcorner.com

I did the following

```
$(window).on({
'DOMMouseScroll mousewheel': ScrollBegin
});

var delta = 0;
var scrollThreshold = 10;

        function ScrollBegin(e) {

        // --- Scrolling up ---
    if (e.originalEvent.detail < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) { 
        delta--;
                    console.log(delta);
        if ( Math.abs(delta) >= scrollThreshold) {
         timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    MoveScreen('up');                        
                }, 800);
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
}

// --- Scrolling down ---
else {

    delta++;
 console.log(delta); 
    if (delta >= scrollThreshold) {
     timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    MoveScreen('down');
                    clearTimeout(timer);

                }, 800);
    }
}

// Prevent page from scrolling
return false;    
        }
```

I don't know what value to set for scrollThreshold.

mousewheel event is raised & ScrollBegin is executed. But this is too slow in IE & too fast in Safari with Apple Mouse.

Mousewheel event is raised for each mouse wheel move. In my case, it raises the event 10 times when I scroll the mouse wheel once. How can I disable those 9 events and only handle it once.

[How to get a MouseWheel Event to fire only once in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123288/how-to-get-a-mousewheel-event-to-fire-only-once-in-jquery?answertab=votes#tab-top) article does  not fix my problem. This only gives support for moving up once & then down once. But I have 5 slides in my page.

Can someone please help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950450/slow-scroll-speed-down

Comment: also visit http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/

Comment: Hi Rachel, Thank you for the urls. nicescroll will not be suitable in my case, since I want to show something like a slideshow. The other link was also not helpful.

Comment: oh well. just thought i'd try. if youre looking for a gallery example visit my gallery at http://www.busyfeet.rachelgallen.com/gallery.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at something like Underscore.js's Debounce function.  You can either use debounce directly by bringing underscore onto your page (not a bad idea), or implement it yourself.  There's also throttle, which works slightly differently; here's an example with both:

http://goo.gl/jEl9lA

Comment: Thank you. This was perfect. I made a little changes to my code and everything worked

Comment: That was perfect @Paul. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use a `debouncer`.

```
//Debouncer functions add a delay between an event and a reaction, so scaling and scrolling don't evoke a function dozens of times.
function debouncer(func, timeout) {
    var timeoutID , timeout = timeout || 200;
    return function () {
        var scope = this , args = arguments;
        clearTimeout( timeoutID );
        timeoutID = setTimeout( function () {
            func.apply( scope , Array.prototype.slice.call( args ) );
        } , timeout );
    };
}
```

This is a general purpose function. Use it like this:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(debouncer(function(){
    //Call your scroll handler here.
}));
```

To really fine tune the delay, add a cecond parameter, like:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(debouncer(function(){
    //Call your scroll handler here.
}), 600);
```

Comment: I would rather do `setTimeout(fn.apply.bind(fn, this, argsCopy), interval);`